# Question about the equation $\int_\Omega \left(\Delta f(x)\right)\overline{g(x)} \ dx \ +\ f(x_0) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$**HYPOTHESIS**

Let $\Omega $ be an open, connected subset of $\R^n$, denote by $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ the functions with compact support in $\Omega$.

Let $x_0 \in \mathrm{int} (\Omega)$ and suppose that    $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ satisfies

$$(*)\quad \quad \int_\Omega \left(\Delta f(x)\right) \overline{g(x)} \ dx \ +\ f(x_0)  = 0 $$

for all $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ and
$$(**) \quad \quad g|_U \equiv 0 $$
where $U\subset \Omega$ is an open ball.

**DEDUCTION**

(*) implies that for all $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega \setminus \{x_0\})$, $\int_\Omega   \left(\Delta f(x)\right) \overline{g(x)} \ dx = 0$, which tells us that $\Delta g = 0$ weakly on $\Omega\setminus\{x_0\}$, and therefore by elliptic regularity ($g\in L^2(\Omega))$ , $g|_{\Omega\setminus \{x_0\}}$  is a *classical* solution, hence is in $C^\infty(\Omega\setminus\{x_0\})$.

Now (**) implies by unique continuation that $g|_{\Omega\setminus \{x_0\}}\equiv 0$ and thus $g|_{\Omega}\equiv 0$.  But this is in contraddiction with $(*)$.

> Is there some hidden mistake in my argument or really  $(*)$ and $(**)$ are incompatible conditions?

I abstracted this from my original problem where instead of the operator $\Delta$ we have a Dirac operator  and instead of $\Omega$ we have a closed manifold.

Comment: Can some function always satisfy (*)? Perhaps I’m missing something, but if it does it for $f$ then it may be hard to satisfy for $f+c$ for all constants $c$ as they only affect the free term, not the laplacian one

Comment: @Ilya Thank you for your comment. $f+c$ is not compactly supported in $\Omega$ though.

The idea is still interesting in the manifold setting (the one I am referring to in the last paragraph). In this case  constants correspond to covariantly constant spinor fields, which however do not always exist (the spin structure must be trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that these are incompatible conditions.  The first hypothesis is the statement that $\Delta g = \delta_{x_0}$ in the sense of distributions.  Therefore $g$ must be a fundamental solution of the Laplacian on the domain $\Omega$, which does not vanish on any open set <strike>(in fact, it must be positive everywhere)</strike>.

I am wrong about the fundamental solution being positive -- this is only true on some manifolds (for example it is positive on $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not on $\mathbb{R}^2$).  However the unique continuation principle you use is valid and, as $g$ is harmonic outside of $x_0$, you are correct that it cannot vanish on an open set.

Comment: Can you provide some references about your last statement? (Not vanishing, positivity?)

Comment: Before accepting the question, let me ask one last thing.
If we are working on a closed manifold, so the equality is $f(x_0) = -\int_M (\Delta f) g$ for all $f\in C^\infty(M)$, then the if we add a constant $c\in \mathbb R$ to $f$, the left hand-side varies while the right hand-side stays the same; does this imply that there are no fundamental solutions on a closed manifold? Seems wrong to me.